# TortoiseHg SSL required but SSL activated

Tags: ssl, mercurial, webserver, tortoisehg

I connect to a repository on my webserver but when I try to push my changes it says :"error 403: ssl required" but in my repository settings I have activated the ssl option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the repository you're not doing it over https.  Type `hg paths` and if the URLs start with `http://` instead of `https://` you're not connecting over https, and that's what Mercurial requires for authenticated actions by default.